# How to show spinner in MVC while loading data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have long operation which retrieves data from my Active Directory and than shows this data in MVC view as table. All works except that it takes 20 seconds to present data. I have question how can i avoid UI blocking and show spinner while data is loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show a loading grpahic, then make an ajax call to fetch the data and when you receive a response from your asynchronous ajax call, show that to the user and hide(or replace) the loading image.

```
<div id="userTable">
  <p>Loading...</p>
  <img src="~/Content/images/loadingimage.png" alt="Please wait" />
</div>
```

and in the document ready event make the ajax call to get the data you want. You can use the jquery `load()` method.

```
$(function(){
   $("#userTable").load("@Url.Action("UserList","Users")");
});
```

Assuming `UserList()` action method in `UsersController` will return a partial view with the markup of tabular data for your user list.

```
public ActionResult UserList()
{
   var useViewModelList = new List<YourUserViewModel>();
   useViewModelList.Add(new YourUserViewModel { Name="Scott" });
   return PartialView(useViewModelList);
}
```

And in your partial view ( ~/Views/Shared/UserList.cshtml),

```
@model List<YourUserViewModel>
<table>
  <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
  @foreach(var item in Model)
  {
    <tr><td>@item.Name</td></tr>
  }
</table>
```